# Which reserved keyword in the F# language spec should be implemented in vNext?

Tags: f#

Now the FSharp v1 has gone into Beta it's time to ask about vNext.

The [FSharp language spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) defines the following reserved keywords:

```
atomic break checked component const constraint constructor    
continue eager fixed fori functor include    
method mixin object parallel params process protected pure    
sealed tailcall trait virtual volatile
```

which of these would you like to see implemented and why?

One keyword per answer please.

Comment: Just when I learn one language, another comes along! Im skipping to Z#

Comment: @Aiden: lol, I actually googled for "Z#"...

Comment: @Bruno, if it exists, im finding another profession.

Comment: @Bruno, I googled too, considering that there's already an X#..

Comment: @Brian, I'd like high-quality answers and am wary of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30492/will-making-my-question-community-wiki-kill-the-incentive-to-post-answers-for-it . I'll turn this into a community wiki within the next week.

Answer (score 7):

trait, assuming trait is something like Scala traits.

Comment: I've upvoted this and started this thread: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/12413.aspx on hubFS with my reasoning and some questions.

Answer (score 4):

My vote is for tailcall.

If I understand the intention correctly this would be a keyword to mark recursive functions the author would intend to be tail recursive. If for whatever reason the compiler cannot comply, a diagnostic message can be of great help.

As it stands now if you fail to structure your recursive function properly the first time you will be informed about this is the StackOverflow exception (No pan intended)

Comment: I was under the impression the F# compiler did issue .tail IL instructions and was able to spot tail call recursion.

Comment: It does if you wrote your function right. But if you did something in it so it cannot be tail recursive - you will not know it until you see the Exception

Comment: No need for a keyword, the compiler should warn me (optionally fail) when it sees a rec function without tail calls anyway.

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen - no it should not. Sometimes tail recursion is not possible. My approach to code quality is 'no warnings', so I do not this warning unless it was my intention for the function to be tail - recursive

Comment: Big +1 for this, it would be a huge boon for performance-sensitive scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I'm somehow not able to follow your link, but in case `atomic` applies to builtin software transactional memory, this is my favorite.

Comment: Yes -- anything that makes safe concurrent code more achievable for mere mortals.

Answer (score 1):

Good question but hard to answer. You can't guess exactly the purpose of each reserved keyword, right?

From my perspective, I could see some useful use cases for `fixed` (fixed size buffers).

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for `eager`, if it meant that evaluation was lazy by default (like in Haskell, but unlike current F#).