# mixin or trait in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Is there a way to achieve a mixin in Ruby or a trait in Scala in F#?

What i want is to basically copy one module into another so that it shares the other modules functionality but is closed for modification. Or, an OOP way of thinking about it, I want multiple inheritance except that the parent object can not be modified.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1805473/162396

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can abuse `inline` and member constraints to do duck typing, which gets you some of the benefits of mixins. For example, you could translate this Ruby code (taken from [this tutorial](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_modules.html)):

```
module Debug
  def whoAmI?
    "#{self.type.name} (\##{self.id}): #{self.to_s}"
  end
end
class Phonograph
  include Debug
  # ...
end
class EightTrack
  include Debug
  # ...
end
ph = Phonograph.new("West End Blues")
et = EightTrack.new("Surrealistic Pillow")
ph.whoAmI?  »   "Phonograph (#537766170): West End Blues"
et.whoAmI?  »   "EightTrack (#537765860): Surrealistic Pillow"
```

to this:

```ml
type Phonograph(id, name) =
  member x.Id : int = id
  override x.ToString() = name

type EightTrack(id, name) =
  member x.Id : int = id
  override x.ToString() = name

module Debug =
  let inline whoAmI x =
    sprintf "%s (%d) : %s" 
      (^T : (member GetType : unit -> Type) x).Name
      (^T : (member Id : int with get) x)
      (^T : (member ToString : unit -> string) x)

let ph = Phonograph(537766170, "West End Blues")
let et = EightTrack(537765860, "Surrealistic Pillow")

Debug.whoAmI ph //"Phonograph (537766170) : West End Blues"
Debug.whoAmI et //"EightTrack (537765860) : Surrealistic Pillow"
```

It has the (arguable) advantage over extension methods of not requiring a common base class or interface. Regarding your previous question about the `open` keyword, you could have several modules defining `whoAmI` and the one `open`ed last will shadow previous ones. In that way you can sort of "mix in" which module you want. The F# core library uses a similar approach with [checked operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340296.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby mixins are best emulated with extension methods (type extensions) in the .NET framework. I don't believe F# has any special language features that more closely resemble mixins, traits, or multiple inheritance.

See this question: [How do I create an extension method (F#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523500/how-do-i-create-an-extension-method-f)

And this description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx

For speed's sake, here's the example given on MSDN:

```
module MyModule1 =

    // Define a type.
    type MyClass() =
      member this.F() = 100

    // Define type extension.
    type MyClass with
       member this.G() = 200

module MyModule2 =
   let function1 (obj1: MyModule1.MyClass) =
      // Call an ordinary method.
      printfn "%d" (obj1.F())
      // Call the extension method.
      printfn "%d" (obj1.G())
```